# Get Profile ID Based on OrgDefinedID

Tags: desire2learn

I'm working on a project where we plan to send some data back to Desire2Learn. I've gotten pretty far, I can query the user list, I can get their profile id, get their profile, and then update said profile.

I noticed when looking through the documentation, that I if I call  `/d2l/api/lp/1.3/users/?OrgDefinedId=123456789` it returns just that one user as seen below.

```
[
    {
        "OrgId": "{{ORG_ID}}",
        "UserId": 12345,
        "FirstName": "Christopher",
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": "Sterling",
        "UserName": "csterli1",
        "ExternalEmail": "{MY_EMAIL}",
        "OrgDefinedId": "123456789",
        "UniqueIdentifier": "{{UID}}",
        "Activation": {
            "IsActive": true
        },
        "DisplayName": "Chris Sterling"
    }
]
```

The problem, I believe, that I've ran into is that in order for me to get the Profile ID, I can't call the url above, but instead, I have to call `/d2l/api/lp/1.3/enrollments/orgUnits/{{ORG_ID}}/users/`. That call there returns the Profile ID, but it also returns all users, in increments of 100.

What I am wondering is if there is a way that I can pass the ?OrgDefinedId to the enrollments method and have it return the user object?

If that isn't the case, I'm wondering, is there a better way to do what I am trying to do. It currently seems like I am going to be making a large number of calls to get all our users so we can get their profile id for a given user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a better filter on the enrollments calls, nor does the profile identifier appear in the administrative user data record returned from the `.../users/` calls.

The [GET classlist for orgunit](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-le-%28version%29-%28orgUnitId%29-classlist-) call also returns data containing user profile identifiers, and it returns data in a JSON array rather than a paged set. The [Enrollment.ClasstlistUser](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#Enrollment.ClasslistUser) structure contains the LMS UserId (`Identifier`) and user profile ID (`ProfileIdentifier`) data and *can* also contain the `OrgDefinedId` property. In order to get back that last data, though, your LMS must be configured to provide org-defined IDs in the Classlist tool. If it's not, then to make the union between profile identifiers and org-defined identifiers, you'll need to use the LMS UserId as the common value, and make a series of calls to get back two data sets you can join together.